# Ecto with basic project

Tags: python, ubuntu, ecto, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-oneiric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !

I use ecto with ubuntu 11.10  and fuerte.

I am a novice with ECTO. T tried to use the following tutorials:
http://ecto.willowgarage.com/releases/amoeba-beta4/ecto/using_ecto/client_usage.html and I have the follow error message:

> Unknown CMake command

> "ecto_python_env_gen".

> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I think it's because the wrong use of the CMakeLists.txt but I don't know why.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31691/ecto-with-basic-project./) by [pelou](https://answers.ros.org/users/2169/pelou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure whether you are using the debs or are compiling from source. In any case ecto_python_env_gen got removed from ecto so you should not face that anymore :)

If you find any other bug, please file a bug report on https://github.com/plasmodic/ecto

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2012-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1